# Confused retrieving values from LinkedHashMap in scala

Tags: scala

Can someone clarify the behaviour of the following code, please?

```
scala> val map =  new collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]]()
map: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]] = Map()

scala> val arr = map.getOrElse("Hi",None)
arr: Serializable with Equals = None
```

Why is arr of type Serializable with Equals and not of ArrayBuffer[String]?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you confused `None` which is of type `Option[Nothing]` with something else, maybe `Nil`? But it has type `List[Nothing]`, which is also wrong. To make this compile correct you should write:

```
scala> map.getOrElse("Hi",ArrayBuffer.empty)
res3: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer()
```